# My file navigator (sidebar) is hidden in Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, file-browser

I am using Elementary OS. I am facing an issue with the file browser. It displays only files and directories inside the home directory. The file navigator (sidebar) is missing and I cannot access  other drives.

[image: file browser screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd>, as it is answered in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1411161).